# What's happen if send an unsupported React-Native component to CodePush?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push, react-native-code-push

According to CodePush documentation, [some React-Native components are not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/README.md#supported-components). Should I take precautions before sending an update to CodePush? Because if I send an unsupported component it may break the update.

In short, Does CodePush accept unsupported components when sending updates?

I don't have a test app to test it so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodePush can't detect and can't block if you make native changes or make a change with not supported components. I tried and see the result. If you send an update which contains native changes or not supported component in changes, it not break the update because CodePush make rollback the update if it sees any crash.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Code Push staging key to run E2E tests on a build with detox before deploying live.